# How do I return different iterators from a function?

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to change the `minigrep` application that I've implemented in the rust book to also take `stdin` input like the real grep does.

I've created a small helper function that takes the configuration and decides (currently according to an environment variable) whether to return the buffered reader iterator or the stdin iterator:

```rust
fn stdinOrFile(cfg: &Cfg) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> + '_ {
    if cfg.stdin {
        return io::stdin().lines();
    }
    
    let file = File::open(cfg.path.clone()).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    return reader.lines();
}
```

Realizing that I'm poking with a stick in the dark, it appears that the syntax of returning a trait object [is legal](https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/06/22/returning-rust-iterators/), it's a dead-end for now thought. The compiler appears to still try to infer the concrete type of the returned value and complains that the other type is not of the same type, however to the best of my knowledge both implement the iterator trait.

Some ideas I have to get around this:

1. `Box` the value before returning it
2. Create a generic wrapper that would wrap both underlying types, then, since the `minigrep` matcher only uses the `filter` functionality of the iterators, I could have separate `filter` implementations on the wrapper according to which underlying type it holds, which would then call the relevant method on the underlying type.

Any ideas?
Why is the trait object syntax allowed in the return type if a concrete implementation is inferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to think you should box it. `impl Iterator` is not a trait object. It can mean a couple of different things, but in return position it's a special [`impl` return syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/impl_trait.html#as-a-return-type). Effectively, the function still returns a concrete, ordinary iterator of known type, it's just that the compiler infers that type for you. It's most commonly used with iterators, since writing `impl Iterator<Item=u32>` is far nicer than the *actual* return type which can be some shenanigans like `Map<Vec::Iter<String>, fn(String) -> i32>` (and can even be non-denotable in cases where the function argument is a closure).

However, with `impl` return, there must still exist a concrete type. You can't return two different types in two different branches. So in this case, you *do* need a trait object. That's `dyn Iterator`, but `dyn Iterator` is not sized, so you need to wrap it in a `Box` to deal with that.

```
Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String> + '_>
```

and, of course, you'll need to wrap your return values in `Box::new`, since Rust won't do that for you.

Comment: Nice. That did the trick. Many thanks

Comment: Using `either` (it is in `itertools` too) is also an option.